# Prevent SeekBar and timers from reset on pause

Tags: java, android, timer, seekbar

I have a seekBar along with a current timer and total time textViews for a simple music playing app. It seems when I pause my music, getDuration and getCurrentPosition both return 0, which is why the current time and total time text both go to 0 and the seekBar resets to the beginning as well. When I resume, everything goes back to where it was, as if there was no issue. Why do getDuration and getCurrentPosition return 0 on pause? Is there a workaround?

I've tried to make a jank solution by setting visibility to gone and creating a new set of two textViews and seekBar that save the times and seekBar just before pausing and show those temporarily, but those are clunky and have a delay so I still see the reset items for a split second. I handle play and pause both in one button. Please let me know if any additional information is needed. Below are my seekBar handling methods, both of which are called in onCreate:

```
/**
 * SeekBar setup and handling
 * TODO: Bug where seekBar sets to 0 when paused. Retains position when resumed.
 */
private void initializeSeekBar() {
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    totalDuration = new TextView(this);
    totalDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalDuration);
    currentDuration = new TextView(this);
    currentDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentDuration);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser && musicBound) {
                // update current time on change
                currentDuration.setText(convertedTime(progress * 1000));
                // update seekBar
                seekTo(progress * 1000);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            musicService.mutePlayer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            musicService.unMutePlayer();
            seekTo(getCurrentPosition());
        }
    });
    // start seekBar updating thread
    run();
}

/**
 * Thread that updates seekBar as song plays
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    updateMetadataDisplay();

    if (musicBound) {
        long totalTime = getDuration();
        long currentTime = getCurrentPosition();

        seekBar.setMax(getDuration() / 1000);
        seekBar.setProgress(getCurrentPosition() / 1000);

        // timers
        totalDuration.setText(convertedTime(totalTime));
        currentDuration.setText(convertedTime(currentTime));
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a system bug. I would just do a workaround by not updating the seekBar when getCurrentPosition() outputs 0.

Example in run():

```
    if (musicBound) {
      long totalTime = getDuration();
      long currentTime = getCurrentPosition();

      if(currentTime == 0)
        return;

      seekBar.setMax(totalTime / 1000);
      seekBar.setProgress(currentTime / 1000);

      // timers
      totalDuration.setText(convertedTime(totalTime));
      currentDuration.setText(convertedTime(currentTime));
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and it causes the seekBar to not start at all, as current time must be 0 at the beginning of a song

Comment: @tiandrew Maybe count how often you did it and only allow it once. So add a variable like `boolean started = false;` then set it the first time the run() method is executed to true and change `if(currentTime == 0)` to `if(currentTime == 0 && started)`. **NOTE: You have to set started to true after the if(current...**

Comment: That manages to save the seekBar position and timers, but now it won't resume moving and updating the time when I resume. When you return in a thread, would you have to restart it somehow?